# Javafx: How to add itmes in checkcombobox?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to add itmes in my checkComboBox but i don't Know why I am failing to do so. Here is what I am trying to do in this:

```
`// initialinzing FXML in my controller`
@FXML
CheckComboBox<String> checkComboBox;

// create the data to show in the CheckComboBox
     final ObservableList<String> strings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
         strings.add("Item " + i);
     }

     // Create the CheckComboBox with the data
     checkComboBox  = new CheckComboBox<String>(strings);


     // and listen to the relevant events (e.g. when the selected indices or
     // selected items change).
     checkComboBox.getCheckModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
         public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) {
             System.out.println(checkComboBox.getCheckModel().getSelectedItems());
         }
     });
     }
```

Comment: It's done.
just made a small change while adding my observable list in my checkcombobox.
checkComboBox.getItems().addAll(strings);
 istead of checkComboBox  = new CheckComboBox<String>(strings);

Comment: Why are you creating a new `CheckComboBox`? Do you add it to the scene anywhere?

Comment: Yes! i added my `checkComboBox` in my scene. That's where I was making mistake by creating a new `checkComboBox`. Instead of making a new checkComboBox I have to directly call the `getItems().addAll(strings)` function to add my ObservableList in my checkComboBox

Comment: I meant "did you add the new combo box you created to the scene", which you presumably didn't. You should probably delete the question, or at least post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Code is Working fine

My fxml code

```
<CheckComboBox fx:id="addFeaturesCheckComboBox" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="192.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
```

My Controller Code:

```
//to initialize my checkComboBox
@FXML
CheckComboBox<String> addFeaturesCheckComboBox;

public void initialize() throws SQLException{

ObservableList<String> strings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
         strings.add("Item " + i);
     }
addFeaturesCheckComboBox.getItems().addAll(strings);
//listen to the relevant events (e.g. when the selected indices or
     // selected items change).

     addFeaturesCheckComboBox.getCheckModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
         public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) {

             selectedFeatures = addFeaturesCheckComboBox.getCheckModel().getSelectedItems();
         }
     });
 }
```